# how to phase? If variable = (condition1) + (anything)

Tags: javascript, html

How would I go about writing this `if statement` in javascript?

```
if(url == "http://www.google.com/" && "*")
  { ... }
```

The `*` needs to be flexible and accept anything added onto the first variable... If no value is assigned to `*`, the condition must still be true...

Comment: Do you mean the value of `url` must start with `http://www.google.com/`?

Comment: Can you give as another example of what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf), like this:

```
if(url.indexOf("http://www.google.com/") == 0)
```

The meaning of this is "url **starts with** `http://www.google.com/`".  Or depending on what you're after, a regex may be better, for example:

```
if(/^http:\/\/www.google.com\//​​​​​​​​.test(url))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this `startsWith` method:

```
String.prototype.startsWith = function(prefix) {
    return this.substr(0, prefix.length) === prefix;
};
```

Then you can use that method on `url` like this:

```
if (url.startsWith("http://www.google.com/"))
```